# Slick: Avoiding asInstanceOf[T] and Improving Type signature

Tags: scala, generics, slick

The code below works, but I can't help but think I am doing something inappropriate with that `asInstanceOf[B]` cast.

Essentially, after passing a `TableQuery` of some type, I want the `mapper` to turn into an action take the results and `map` it into a list of DAOs according to a function I pass to it.

What I am stuck on is the type of the function, or perhaps how expose the inner type of the TableQuery type. I want to do something like `[B <: TableElementType]` `f: B => A` instead of the potentially brutal cast to B.

I guess I think that I know that I am going to get something like an `AgencyRow` in the example below to map to an AgencyDAO, how can I capture that in the type signature of the method?

**Mapper**

```scala
  def mapper[A <: BaseDAO, B <: DatabaseAccessObject, T <: TableQuery[E], E <: AbstractTable[_]](query: T, f: B => A) : Seq[A] = {
    val result = exec(query.result)
    result.map(o => f(o.asInstanceOf[B]))
  }

  def exec[T](action: DBIO[T]): T = Await.result(db.run(action), 4 seconds)
```

**Consuming Mapper (Test Code)**

```scala
val list = mapper[AgencyDAO, AgencyRow, TableQuery[Agency], Agency](agencies, AgencyDAODomainObject.convertFromRow)
        list.length should equal(75)
```

**Slick Schema**

```scala
case class AgencyRow(id: Int, name: Option[String] = None) extends DatabaseAccessObject

class Agency(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[AgencyRow](_tableTag, "agency") {
   def * = (id, name) <>(AgencyRow.tupled, AgencyRow.unapply)
   def ? = (Rep.Some(id), name).shaped.<>({ r => import r._; _1.map(_ => AgencyRow.tupled((_1.get, _2))) }, (_: Any) => throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))

   val id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
   val name: Rep[Option[String]] = column[Option[String]]("name", O.Length(200, varying = true), O.Default(None))
}

lazy val Agency = new TableQuery(tag => new Agency(tag))enter code here
```

**DAO Mapper**

```scala
package object Implicits {
   implicit class DomainObjectOps[A <: BaseDAO](a: A)(implicit ev: DomainObject[A]) {
   def name = ev.name(a)
   def id = ev.id(a)
  }
}   

trait BaseDAO
trait DomainObject[A <: BaseDAO] {
  def id(a: A): Int
  def name(a: A): String
}

case class AgencyDAO(val id: Int, val name: String) extends BaseDAO
object AgencyDAO {
  implicit object AgencyDAODomainObject extends DomainObject[AgencyDAO] {
    def convertToRow(o: AgencyDAO) = AgencyRow(o.id, Some(o.name))
    def convertFromRow(o: AgencyRow) = AgencyDAO(o.id, o.name.getOrElse(""))

    override def id(a: AgencyDAO) = a.id
    override def name(a: AgencyDAO) = a.name
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the signature of `TableQuery.result` that you used in your first line of `mapped`? I can't seem to find [its definition](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/api/index.html#slick.lifted.TableQuery).

Comment: @dcastro so, my understanding is that it is an instance of a [DBIOAction](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/dbio.html?highlight=result), but it is database driver specific (exposed by importing the appropriate api)  so you end up getting something like [PostgresDriver.StreamingDriverAction](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/api/index.html#slick.driver.PostgresDriver@StreamingDriverAction[+R,+T,-E<:slick.dbio.Effect]=slick.profile.FixedSqlStreamingAction[R,T,E])

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else might possibly find this relevant or instructive: rather than call `result`on the query inside the mapper, it is passed in with `result` already called, which returns a `DBIOAction[R]`. Slick has a convenient alias `DBIO[R]`, and `R` can be asked to extend a `Seq[B]` eliminating the need for a cast. So now:

#### Updated Mapper

```
def resultMapper[A <: BaseDAO, B <: DatabaseAccessObject, S <: DBIO[Seq[B]]](action: S)(implicit rowMapper: B => A) : Seq[A] = {
   val result = exec(action)
   result.map(rowMapper)
}
```

#### Updated Call

```
implicit val rowMapper: AgencyRow => AgencyDAO = AgencyDAODomainObject.convertFromRow
val action = agencies.result //turns query to DBIOAction
val list = resultMapper[AgencyDAO, AgencyRow, DBIO[Seq[AgencyRow]]](action)
```